# Part of the table to fetch data from sql & rest column redy for user input

Tags: php

I have table which fetch data from my sql. Out of 6 columns I am fetching data from mysql for only first 4 columns & 5th & 6th column is ready for user input. I will not be storing data in same table from where I a fetching information. My issue is 5th column 1st entry starts from last row of the data which I get from mysql.

I have attached image to explain it better

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYTbM.png)

```
<table border="1">

<tr>
<th>Material</th>
<th>Material Description</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Unit of Measure</th>
<th>Accepted Quantity</th>
<th>Return Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<?php
while($SSTR=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$SSTR['dmaterial']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$SSTR['dmdescription']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$SSTR['dquantity']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$SSTR['duom']."</td>";

//echo "</tr>";
}
?>  
<?php
    $numbers=$rowcount;
    for($i=1;$i<=$numbers;$i++)
    {
    ?>

<td>
<input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty" type="text" autofocus>
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Return Qty" name="rqty" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
    </table>


<input name="Accept_Stock" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Where do you want this 5th and 6th column to start from?

Comment: from 1st row its starting from last row of data fetched from myql screenshot will help you to understand my issue

Comment: I've given answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that `for` loop at all, simply change the `while` in the following way,

```
while($SSTR=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$SSTR['dmaterial'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$SSTR['dmdescription'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$SSTR['dquantity'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$SSTR['duom'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty" type="text" autofocus></td>';
        echo '<td><input placeholder="Return Qty" name="rqty" type="text"></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

---

Not related to your question but considering the future scope of the code, you might get into some trouble, like how do you associate *accepted quantity* and *return quantity* to a particular row? For this, consider changing the `name` attribute of your input elements in the following way, (assuming *id* is the actual column of your table)

```
<input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty[<?php echo $SSTR['id']; ?>]" type="text" autofocus>
<input placeholder="Return Qty" name="rqty[<?php echo $SSTR['id']; ?>]" type="text">
```

This way it would be easier to catch hold of the *accepted quantity* and *return quantity* of particular table row when you submit the form.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, Thanks for the detailed answer. there is small uery which is I don't want accepted qty to be greater than dquantity which is fethed from database how can I write this in below line   echo '<td><input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty" type="number"  max " "autofocus></td>';

Comment: @KiranChandekar Change *that* input element in the following way, `echo '<td><input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty" type="number" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'" autofocus></td>';`

Comment: Hi Rajdeep I am getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'userref' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  when I am using code >>>>>  echo '<td><input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty[<?php echo $SSTR['userref']; ?>]" type="number" min="0" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'" autofocus></td>';

Comment: @KiranChandekar Your *input* element should be like this: `echo '<td><input placeholder="Accepted Qty" name="aqty[' . $SSTR['userref'] . ']" type="number" min="0" max="'. $SSTR['dquantity'] .'" autofocus></td>';`